# A two (plus one) dimensional colorspace with brown in the middle? Preferably usable in Python

Tags: python, colors, color-space

**Short form**: is there any color space similar to [CIELab](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CIELAB_color_space#CIELAB) but with the middle position on the two color axes occupied by browns rather than greys, as sketched below? Ideally with a Python interface to convert to and from RGB.

Values on a third, 'lightness' dimension would take each of these possible colors from black to white.

[link to image (sorry, not enough rep here to put it inline)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k1K99.png)

**Context**: For a simulation, every entity can vary on two variables. When visualizing the entities I'd like to use color to give a fairly intuitive idea of the two values for each entity. RGB does not seem a convenient color space for this, as changes in values do not very intuitively correspond to changes in color. CIELab (see above link) is much closer to what I need, as it has two color dimensions (red-to-green, yellow-to-blue) plus a Lightness dimension; and there already exists [a python module](https://python-colormath.readthedocs.io/en/latest/color_objects.html#labcolor) to do the math. The one hitch for me: a value of zero on both color dimensions results in a shade of grey (black at Lightness=0 and white at L=100). Instead I would like lightness level (with black and white as extremes) to only come in if the visualisation involves shading; with a flat, unshaded visualization there should be no black, white or grey. For the middle position on the two color axes, brown seems somehow intuitive to me - perhaps because mixing multiple paint colors often seems to give brown.

Maybe such a consistent color space is difficult/impossible to construct as the brown in the middle might conflict with e.g. dark shades of orange. As a 'color novice' I'd just welcome some input whether something like this exists or is at all possible.

I suppose I could associate variable values and RGB color values by hand. But that seems cumbersome and inelegant if there exists a more consistent way.

Comment: Seems like you need a subtractive colourspace, e.g. CMYK, so that “adding” colour result in something closer to what happens in printing and painting. It might be worth looking at the work of Brien Diterle in Mypaint.

Comment: Thanks @KelSolaar; CMYK didn't look intuitive for my purposes, but your comment made me reconsider subtractive systems, in particular the paint-based RYB system. That isn't necessarily a fully fleshed out color space, but [this blog post](http://sue.codes/math-art/2015/03/30/color-spaces.html) and [this paper](https://bahamas10.github.io/ryb/assets/ryb.pdf) give a simple way to make one: define a RYB cube in RGB coordinates, then interpolate sensibly. It has one color dimension more than I need, but I can put it to use. The result may be more intuitive still than using a CIElab style space.